# Using pdflatex in a pipeline

Tags: pdftex

I have a document which is currently compiled using a makefile that I would like to transition into a pipeline. All `make` is doing is running `pdflatex` and putting the file in my current directory.

```
.SUFFIXES: .tex .pdf

.tex.pdf:
    pdflatex $<
```

I also have a few other scripts I want to run on the final PDF - cribbed from @mattmight, as you do :)

- `weasel-words.sh`
- `passive-voice.sh`
- `duplicates.pl`

By their names, you can see what each of these do. I'm thinking I might do something like the following:

`pdflatex test.tex | weasel-words | passive-voice | duplicates | aspell`

The files I mentioned are all in the same directory. I'm getting `aspell` via Homebrew, so it's already in my `$PATH`.

As I said, `make` isn't really doing anything special for me here and the syntax is a bit weird compared to typical shell scripting (Just my opinion).

Does this make sense?

Comment: tex can not write the pdf to standard out (but why use make if you just want to run pdftex once)

Comment: why not `pdflatex test; cat test.pdf | weasel-words | passive-voice | duplicates | aspell`  (passing the pdf to aspell???)

Comment: Huh. Maybe this is because of `cat`, but I end up with test.pdf and test.pdf.new, should this be explicitly redirected to replace the file with `>`? Also, running these scripts is partially borked because in each case the tools pause the execution if it finds something (E.g, not found or a match). Running the scripts as standalone, returns the prompt as normal w/ no errors.

`./build: line 5: weasel-words.sh: command not found`

Comment: When you compile, be sure to check your compression settings are explicitly set to ones you know work.  You don't necessarily get the text in the pdf.  Anyway it might be interrupted by objects, which could obstruct your scripts.  Why not work on the .tex file? I know aspell can, and without the source of the others assume they're meant for text rather than pdfs.

Comment: @ChrisH Hmm. That might be better as I could move the pipe to the beginning and then run `pdflatex` at the end.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The purpose of this was to send the `.tex` source in, do things to it (e.g, the scripts), then run it through `pdflatex` and get the finished PDF back out, replacing the existing PDF (which is now old). Thus, I only need to run my compile script and everything happens automatically after that.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I originally tried it with PDF because I wasn't sure that `aspell` and the others wouldn't get false positives from the `.tex` file. In retrospect, this was dumb and it works fine. The weirdness I'm trying to understand mainly comes from the fact the scripts (in particular the spell check) prompts interaction from the user and doesn't simply run.

Comment: but are the scripts using the piped input at all or are they just getting the tex file, if so how?

Comment: aspell has a tex mode (and you can add to the list of macros it knows about, specifying whether their arguments are to be checked or not). It's interactive and designed to modify its input. I've never piped through it but don't see what you couldn't. I don't know about the other tools.